# Im logging 'recommends' on line 28 but im just getting back a bunch of empty arrays, I'm guessing my useEffect isn't written correctly. (no errors)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT2qZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAOOY.png)

I'm pulling from my firestore DB and when I log 'recommends' it should pull the movies with the type of 'recommend' but I am just getting empty arrays.

Comment: You should add your code as text

Comment: Updating a state will cause all of your arrays to disappear. You should use state instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.